# Query for relaxing condition with good performance?

Tags: sql, search, plsql

I have the code that does something like this:

```
Search(for 'this' using 'a','b','c','d')
if result is not found
    search(for 'this' using null,'b','c','d')
    if result is not found
      ...
      if result is not found
           search(for 'this' using null,null,null,null)
 ...
return
```

It's Stored Procedure that calls itself recursively but with less parameters.
Inside the function are one dynamic query that is generated based on the parameters (some parameters involve joining another tables, some are just additional conditions in where clause)

I was told that this waste the performance as it needs to re-search the whole table again and again.

I kind of have the idea that if we search everything first then from that result we start to filter it. It might be better.

What can I do to improve the code? Is there a way to achieve the same results via normal query?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a UNION, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL1='A'     AND COL2='B' AND COL3 = 'C' AND COL4 = 'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL1 IS NULL AND COL2='B' AND COL3 = 'C' AND COL4 = 'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL1 IS NULL AND COL2 IS NULL AND COL3 = 'C' AND COL4 = 'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL1 IS NULL AND COL2 IS NULL AND COL3 IS NULL AND COL4 = 'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE
  WHERE COL1 IS NULL AND COL2 IS NULL AND COL3 IS NULL AND COL4 IS NULL
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I've tried your logic and it does give the correct result. However it doesn't improve the performance. The search should stop if they already found the result since the first query, therefore the performance is not good.